# MVC 4 Bundlings are not renderd after hosting in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, .net-4.5, bundling-and-minification, bootstrap-4

I have hosted MVC 4 application in IIS. Which is developed using **.Net 4.5**.  After hosting CSS and JS are not rendering in **IE11** but it works in **Chrome**

Below is the **BundledConfig.cs**

[image]

In **Layout.cshtml** i have called to render

[image]

While Running in IE11 in Network tab it shows as below,
[image]

Comment: Did you add `static files` support for `MVC`?

Comment: Yes...In iis right?@VMAtm

Comment: In `MVC` with `AddStaticFiles`

Comment: No I didn't add static files to mvc

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: What type of static file you are  mentioning.. Actually I am newbie to mvc

Comment: Google the method `AddStaticFiles`. Maybe it will help

Comment: But hosted application works fine in chrome browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer,
Application was not working properly in **IE 7** mode and changed to **Edge** mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```